# date and time in delphi

Tags: delphi, datetime

hey, what do i have to write, if i want date&time which updates itself?
Label3.Caption := TimeToStr(Time)
this just shows me the time, when i opened the program, but i want a time, that updates to the form every second (--> like a normal clock does).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Drop a TTimer object on your form

2) Set its 'Interval' propert to 1000 and its 'Enabled' property to true.

3) Double click on it to create an OnTimer event handler. Modify it som it looks something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Label3.Caption := TimeToStr(Time)
end;
```

And there you have it...

Comment: Nice answer, you beat me too it ;o)

Comment: Note that this won't update if the main thread is busy - e.g. loading or saving data, unless there is a call to Application.ProcessMessages as the windows timer message won't be processed.

Comment: @Gerry: True. But since using the VCL from multiple threads is out of the question, without Application.ProcessMessages() there is no way *at* *all* to keep anything in the GUI updated during long-running tasks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Timer](http://docs.codegear.com/docs/radstudio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ExtCtrls_TTimer.html) component to update the label caption every second.

1. Drop a timer on your form.
2. Set the [Interval](http://docs.codegear.com/docs/radstudio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ExtCtrls_TTimer_Interval.html) property to 500, which will update the caption every half second.
3. Set the Enabled property to true.
4. Double click on the timer and add the following code.

   Label3.Caption := TimeToStr(Time)

You can also use the [FormatDateTime](http://docs.codegear.com/docs/radstudio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_FormatDateTime@string@TDateTime.html) function, to change how time is displayed

Answer (score 2):

So drop a timer on the form, set to tick every 500ms or so, and write the time to your text time field in the event handler for the timer. You need to tick faster than smallest time interval you want to display. Note also that windows timers are pretty low priority, so if the CPU gets loaded, your timer might seem to "stick".